# How to quantify this statement

Tags: real-analysis, analysis, proof-writing

How do I quantify this statement?

Let $x \in \mathbb{R}$.  $1 \le x \le 2$ if and only if $1 \le x \le 1+ 1/n$
for some $n \in \mathbb{N}$.

When I am trying to prove this, I am led (in the course of proving the reverse implication) to an existential implication:

There exists an $n \in \mathbb{N}$ such that if $1 \le x \le 1+ 1/n$ then $1 \le x \le 2$.

Which I know to be meaningless, so I guess there is something wrong with how I am interpreting/quantifying the statement?

Now I know that $n = 1$, gives me $1 \le x \le 2$ but to me the statement says something along the lines of "If we have an x such that $1 \le x \le 1+ 1/n$ for some $n$, then by necessity it must be that $ 1 \le x \le 2$" Which to me seems almost like a uniqueness statement since I certainly cannot plug any other natural number in for $n$ to get $1 \le x \le 2$. Furthermore, when using an existential quantified statement as an assumption aren't I prohibited from plugging in a specific value in for $n$ by the rule of existential instantiation?

So to clarify my question, how do I quantify the original statement to avoid the existential implication, or if the existential implication is allowed, why? and why am I permitted to pick a value for $n$?

Comment: I just read the first two lines of the question. So I don't know if this helps: $$\forall x\in \mathbb R\left(1\leq x\leq 2\iff \exists n\in \mathbb N\left(1\leq x\leq 1+\dfrac 1 n\right)\right).$$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think it is that straightforward. The reverse implication is trivially true. If there exists an $n \in \mathbb{N}$ such that $1 \leq x \leq 1+1/n$, then $x$ must necessarily lie in $[1,2]$, since $\sup_{n \in \mathbb{N}}{(1+1/n)}=2$.

Note that for any $n \neq 1$, $x$ must still lie in $[1,2]$ even though $x\neq 2$.

Comment: I thought that implications can never have an existentially quantified statement in the antecedent since they will always be true regardless if the premise is true or not.

Comment: You want to prove that if $1 \leq x \leq 1+1/n$ for some $n \in \mathbb{N}$, then $1 \leq x \leq 2$. It may be that such an $n$ does not exist, in which case the antecedent is false.

Comment: Your right, I think I am just overthinking it.

Answer (score 0):

You put "if" in the wrong place:

- There exists an n ∈ ℕ such that if 1≤x≤1+1/n then 1≤x≤2

should be

- If there exists an n ∈ ℕ such that 1≤x≤1+1/n then 1≤x≤2.